# FILLFACTOR on empty database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-performance

I have a system which populates an empty database with many millions of records.

The database has various types of indexes, the ones I'm worried about are:

1. Indices on foreign keys. These are non-clustered, and not necessarily inserted in sequential order.
2. Indices on BINARY(32) fields. These are content hashes and not ordered at all. Basically, these are like GUIDS and not sequential.

So as the data is bulk-inserted, there is significant fragmentation of these indices.

**Question 1**: if I set FILLFACTOR=75 to these indices when database is created, will it have any effect at all as the data is inserted? It seems FILLFACTOR has effect *after* data is created not *before*. Or will new index pages be allocated with original fillfactor setting?

**Question 2**: what other recommended strategies can I use to make sure these indices perform optimally?

Answer (score 1):

**Question1:**
Fill factor is used only when indexes are rebuilt,SQL doesnt try to store pages based on fill factor while doing inserts.

**Question2:**
It depends on what you are saying as optimal.On a minimal you can check whether your indexes are usefull and your queries are using your indexes.There are tons of best practices around indexes like selective first key,small keys..

Its good to search for any thing about indexes from Kimberly Tripp and DBA.SE

**References:**
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2530-fill-factor/
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/category/indexes/

Answer (score 0):

Check the index fragmentation as well as the write/read ration. If the write/read ratio is very high AND you see fragmentation, you can experiment with adding a fillfactor during index rebuild operation.

The amount of fill-factor really depends on your fragmentation you are seeing. If you see 0-20% fragmentation (and these happened over a period of time), you may not want any  fill-factor. If you see 20-40% fragmentation, you may try 90%.

Lastly get a good index maintenance plan. [Ola Hallengren's index script](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) is excellent. 
NB: Above suggestions are just suggestions - your